# How to generate signature based on payload with both Chinese and English in it python

Tags: python, hash, jupyter-notebook

I try to generate the signature (sign) by python code below with several times of edition but always get the wrong sign, would be really appreciate if someone could help with this:

```
import hashlib
import json

import requests

nick = ['奇思种子']
key = 'd0da37aaab474d0195cf649c889f8d34'
param = {"method":"gy.erp.shop.get","appkey":"114888","sessionkey":"3fa8000e6e844a5d865c27d4e7e1175c","page_size":"100"}
# param['nick'] = str(nick[0].encode('utf-8')) 
param['nick'] = str(nick[0]) 
pjson = json.dumps(param)


postdata = {'param': pjson }

str1 = key + pjson + key 
str2 = str1.replace(": ", ":") 
str3 = str2.replace(", ", ",") 

md = hashlib.md5()
md.update(str3.encode())
sign = md.hexdigest().upper()
param["sign"] = sign

pjson2 = json.dumps(param)
str_2 = pjson2.replace(": ", ":") 
str_3 = str_2.replace(", ", ",")
```

Comment: It is better if you can add the expected results and actual results of your issue.

Comment: Ture, thank you for the comment: actual result: 15DE9A888B13427298DCC6F56FD6CB0B, expected result: B2BA87F21DCC93572F0F217E89AEB473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `ensure_ascii` attribute to False.

```
import hashlib
import json

import requests

nick = ['奇思种子']
key = 'd0da37aaab474d0195cf649c889f8d34'
param = {"method":"gy.erp.shop.get","appkey":"114888","sessionkey":"3fa8000e6e844a5d865c27d4e7e1175c","page_size":"100"}
# param['nick'] = str(nick[0].encode('utf-8')) 
param['nick'] = str(nick[0]) 
pjson = json.dumps(param, ensure_ascii=False)


postdata = {'param': pjson }

str1 = key + pjson + key 
str2 = str1.replace(": ", ":") 
str3 = str2.replace(", ", ",") 

md = hashlib.md5()
md.update(str3.encode('utf-8'))
sign = md.hexdigest().upper()
param["sign"] = sign

pjson2 = json.dumps(param)
str_2 = pjson2.replace(": ", ":") 
str_3 = str_2.replace(", ", ",")
```

Comment: Glad I could help :) Have a great day!